# Difference between Multidimensional and Flattened Arrays in Random Forest Processing in python

Tags: python-3.x, multidimensional-array, random-forest

Hellow!

I've got a question in python processing

I've used CPU Ryzen 9 3950x.

So i tried to run Random forest with CPU.

I use the below code

```
import csv
from math import sqrt
from PIL import Image
from osgeo import gdal
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error


class CalculateIndex():

    def __init__(self, train, target, pif):
        self.train = train
        self.target = target

        self.train_image = gdal.Open(self.train)
        self.target_image = gdal.Open(self.target)

        self.train_array = self.train_image.ReadAsArray()
        self.target_array = self.target_image.ReadAsArray()

        if len(self.train_array.shape) == 2:
            self.band = 1
            self.height, self.width = self.train_array.shape

        else:
            self.band, self.height, self.width = self.train_array.shape

        if len(self.train_array.shape) == 2:
            self.band = 1
            self.height, self.width = self.train_array.shape

        else:
            self.band, self.height, self.width = self.train_array.shape

        self.pif_array =gdal.Open(pif).ReadAsArray()
        self.pif_location =np.where(self.pif_array!=0,self.pif_array,self.pif_array)


        print(self.pif_location)

    def intensity_index(self):

        self.all_train_intensity = []
        self.all_target_intensity = []

        self.pif_train_intensity = []
        self.pif_target_intensity = []

        for i in range(self.band):

            each_train =self.train_array[i,:,:]
            each_target =self.target_array[i,:,:]

            # Doesn't use RESHAPE 
            #self.all_train_intensity.append(each_train)
            #self.all_target_intensity.append(each_target)

            # use RESHAPE 
            self.all_train_intensity.append(each_train.reshape(1, -1))
            self.all_target_intensity.append(each_target.reshape(1, -1))

            each_train_pif =np.where(self.pif_location==0,self.train_array[i,:,:],0)
            each_target_pif =np.where(self.pif_location==0,self.target_array[i,:,:],0)

            # Doesn't use RESHAPE
            #self.pif_train_intensity.append(each_train_pif)
            #self.pif_target_intensity.append(each_target_pif)

            # use RESHAPE
            self.pif_train_intensity.append(each_train_pif.reshape(1, -1))
            self.pif_target_intensity.append(each_target_pif.reshape(1, -1))

    def save_image(self, image_array, image_name, data_type):

        trans = self.train_image.GetGeoTransform()
        proj = self.train_image.GetProjection()

        outdriver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')

        ## Data Type
        if data_type == "uint8":
            data_type_name = gdal.GDT_Byte

        elif data_type == "uint16":
            data_type_name = gdal.GDT_Uint16

        elif data_type == "float":
            data_type_name = gdal.GDT_Float64

        ## Image save
        if len(image_array.shape) == 2:
            outdata = outdriver.Create(image_name, self.width, self.height, 1, data_type_name)
            outdata.SetGeoTransform(trans)
            outdata.SetProjection(proj)
            outdata.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(image_array)

        else:
            outdata = outdriver.Create(image_name, self.width, self.height, image_array.shape[0], data_type_name)
            outdata.SetGeoTransform(trans)
            outdata.SetProjection(proj)

            for i in range(image_array.shape[0]):
                outdata.GetRasterBand(i + 1).WriteArray(image_array[i, :, :])


    def machine_learning(self, prediction_name):

        prediction_array = np.zeros((self.band, self.height, self.width), dtype = np.float64)

        for i in range(self.band):
            print(i)
            model =RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=32,n_jobs=26)

            model.fit(self.pif_train_intensity[i],
                      self.pif_target_intensity[i])

            print(np.shape(self.all_train_intensity))
            prediction =model.predict(self.all_train_intensity[i])
            print(np.shape(prediction))

            rmse = sqrt(mean_squared_error(prediction, self.all_target_intensity[i]))
            print(rmse)
            print(np.shape(prediction))

            # Doesn't use  RESHAPE
            #prediction_array[i, :, :] = prediction
            # use RESHAPE
            prediction_array[i, :, :] =prediction.reshape(1000,1000)

        CalculateIndex.save_image(self,prediction_array, prediction_name, "float")



if __name__ == "__main__":

    train = "train.tif"
    target = "target.tif"
    pif = "cva_binary.tif"

    prediction_name = "predction.tif"

    ci = CalculateIndex(train, target, pif)
    ci.intensity_index()
    ci.machine_learning(prediction_name)
```

I run two case about multi dimension and not. (does'nt use reshape, or use reshape)

Multi dimension case have caused a very serious load. (cpu loaded 100 percents, and degrees reach 100 degrees.)

However, the reshape case was fast and also lightly loaded.(cpu loaded 30 percents, and degrees reach 50degrees.)

Why make this happen?

Because the dimension?.. instruction offset change?\

thanks for read